# Class with list elements of child class, removing on action of child class?

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm having a parent class, call it Worker, which just has a list of elements of a child class, lets call it child.

```
    public class Worker
    {
        private List<Child> subscriptions = new List<Child>();

        public void Subscribe(string pID)
        {
            Child temp = new Child();
            subscriptions.Add(temp);
        }
    }
```

What i'm doing is that every Child that gets created and added runs a separate Thread with some computing in it.
Now I'm getting the case that if a Child Process fails, whatever the reason, my Parent class isn't able to notify that and therefore can't remove the "failed Child" from the list.
My question therefore is:

How do i notify my parent class of a "faulty" list element out of the failing child class?

Comment: did you try to pass an `Action` to the child object that it calls from within its failure code?

Comment: That sounds exactly like something i should try, how do I implement such an `Action`?

Comment: Event or create public method RemoveChild(Child child) in class Worker which will started from calculate method when something will happen and remove child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Worker` wants to be aware when `Child` require its attention

This looks like an `Observer` pattern, where `Worker` can `GetFaulty(Child faulty)` while `Child` wants to `Notify`

```
public class Child
{
    // some code

    public Worker Parent { get; set; }

    // This is called when the process fails
    public void Notify()
    {
        Parent.GetFaulty(this);
    }

    // more code
}

public class Worker
{
    private List<Child> subscriptions = new List<Child>();

    public void Subscribe(string pID)
    {
        Child temp = new Child { Parent = this };
        subscriptions.Add(temp);
    }

    public void GetFaulty(Child faulty)
    {
        subscriptions.Remove(faulty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly how i solved it a few seconds ago. Nice explanation, thank you. Didn't now that this is officially known as a design pattern!

Comment: I suggest you [this reading](https://exceptionnotfound.net/tag/designpatterns/)

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it, I simply passed down the Worker to the Childs on creation as a parent attribute, this way i can call parent.DestroyAction in the failure code of the child.

I guess thats not best practice but it works for me.

Thanks for the insightful comments!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your existing sctructure you can opt to go for events like so:

```
public class Child
{
    public event Action<Child> OnFault;

    public async Task DoWork()
    {
        try {
            // you do what you gotta do
        }
        catch {
            if(OnFault !=null) OnFault(this);
        }
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    private List<Child> subscriptions = new List<Child>();

    public void Subscribe(string pID)
    {
        Child temp = new Child();       
        temp.OnFault += (x) => subscriptions.Remove(x); // set an event handler to remove that particular instance from the list
        subscriptions.Add(temp);
    }
}
```